# Example for Delphi Prism

Tags: delphi-prism

Im new in delphi prism.

im looking for some example but i didnt found any goof webpages or resources ...

any one have a good one?

i found some in [remobjects](http://code.remobjects.com/) but they are not complete solution and projects(just a little codes).

Comment: What kind of example are you looking for? Winform, WPF, Console App?

Comment: Are you really sure? There are at least 12 different categories of demos and plenty of demos in them that came with Delphi Prism. I think, you are not looking in the right location. Do a search for say the word Mono or Windows Form and you will find the demos for Delphi Prism. These ones you don't have to do anything. Just load the project file and run. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should look in the Demos that ship with Delphi Prism. They should be located somewhere in the Shared Users / Documents / Projects path.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the demo apps that come with the Delphi Prism installation (in the Sample Demo directory as mentioned by Sebastian) you can also have a look at: http://code.remobjects.com/  there are some more elaborated projects that are built using Delphi Prism.